# JQuery Post Can't Reach Controller One Folder Above Root

Tags: php, jquery, document-root

Haven't had much luck with my keywords in Google or here so I'm asking this even though I am sure its trivial...

I want to use a JQuery `$.POST` method to ask for information from a controller that is located above the server root... I have found answers in .ASP and J2EE but not simple PHP/HTML/etc...

This controller does not need to be instantiated so the simple URL should be enough to send it info and ask for a response. I have used JQuery a long time so I don't need answers that ask if I am using .POST correctly as I have used this AJAX method for over two years.... Just not in MVC architecture.

I have a PHP MVC built site that I am running and I basically just want to get some info from my controller so I am trying this `$.post("../../../controller/controllerScript.php", {...}, function() {...})` ... I also have tried removing each of the `../` individually and tested each. No luck... So far I am getting consistent error 404 messages that it can't find the file. This makes sense to me because this is above the server root and shouldn't be publicly accessible.

I am aware that this is because I am looking for a file above the server root but I thought that was supposed to be the magic of MVC that I can set the root to the public folder and have a lot more security and clear programming. I know the problem probably lies in needing an .HTACCESS file which I suck at doing, or some other URL redirection method but I just don't know which.

My server folder architecture

```
-controller
    -fileINeed.php
-model
-public
    -js
        -myPOSTfunction
-view
```

I thought a simple `action="../../../controller/fileINeed.php"` would at least let me submit the form to an empty page so I could debug it but even this cant be found. It changes the URL to `//BASE/controller/fileINeed.php` which I am sure is part of the server security to files above the root.

Anyone able to quickly give me a MVC-101 schooling and show me how dumb I am? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is JQuery is a client side language, thus is restricted to the document root and cannot traverse above, this is a security feature because if a JQuery could traverse above root so could your visitors and this would cause major security issues. Depending on how your server is set up you can use the JQuery to call a php or any other server side application that resides inside the root then inside that script make a call or reference a app located above it.

Create a caller php inside public\ then include it from there

```
include('/home/controller/fileINeed.php');
```

Keeping in mind you need to figure out the directory structure between your server root and the public folder and replace /home with it. some use /www.

Comment: I figured as much but do I really have to redirect this back through the index.php?somevar=whatever route? I have so many pages going through here it seems silly or way too much. I also don't want to have to make another object to instantiate (a new controller obj) in my page controller class called from index.php. I was hoping my AJAX calls could remain little non-classed scripts... thoughts?

Comment: I would not use a somevar=../parent-root/app.php because that opens your server up to attacks in the same way just having an openly accessible parent root folder. You are better off hard coding the include. Can I ask why the scripts NEED to be above root?

Comment: well they are controllers. I assumed it was proper MVC architecture to keep the server folder chain as I mentioned in my post with the four folders controller, model, public and view. I suppose I could put this script in the public folder I just wanted to learn the actual correct way to do this since I keep coming across it as a problem.

Comment: @GoreDefex creating a chained caller in the public folder is the correct way them, I was just curious as to why, there are many other people who use above public code as well there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: sweet! now were talking that sounds much more like the answer I am looking for. Chained caller you say. Time for research mode to activate!

Comment: to get technical php actually calls it chained includes, same difference though.

Comment: much appreciated sir. Looking now I will be back asap if there are more questions that arise. *Tip my hat* to you good sir! :)

Comment: lol this is so infuriating... maybe my keywords suck? I dunno... but I cannot find any good examples of PHP Include Chaining or Chained anything really... so frusterating that I can't even just use an action-"../controller/fileINeed.php" to debug this problem. Even that doesn't want to let me see above the root and its in PHP... hmmm

Comment: all you need is `include('/home/controller/fileINeed.php');`

Comment: but the controller folder is not in the home/root dir. Its above it. So wouldn't it be home/../controller/fileINeed.php  ?

Comment: no, includes do not root in the public folder, PHP is server side code so its root is the actual server root.

Comment: perhaps maybe it is me who misunderstands. My server is not 'choosing' to root in the public folder because of HTACCESS or anything else. I have actually placed the root folder as the public folder. Does that still make it accessible?

Comment: The servers root is not the same as your public or document root, folders can be above your public folder but still below your servers root. Again without knowong your servers configuration the folder names are a guess but if your document path is /home/www/public/js your path for server side includes and references would be /home/www/controller